# How to get number of same id's where the item was found in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have table like this:

| some_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 |
| 2 | 2022-02-02 |
| 3 | 2022-02-03 |
| 3 | 2022-02-04 |
| 3 | 2022-02-05 |
| 3 | 2022-02-06 |

I want to get the number of rows based on the id where the date was found?

I tried this but it's not working:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM dates WHERE date = '2022-02-04'
```

Expected output should be `4` rows since there are 4 same id's where the `2022-02-04` was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl 
WHERE id IN (
 SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE `date`='2022-02-04'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

An `exists` query should do it:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*)
FROM t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t AS x
    WHERE x.id = t.id
    AND x.date = '2022-02-04'
)
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

Using exists logic we can try:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dates d1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dates d2
              WHERE d2.some_id = d1.some_id AND
                    d2.date = '2022-02-04');
```